# Magento 2 How to bind knockout event on ajax html response

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

I have created custom functionality on item form on cart page like increment/decrement qty, remove product with a custom popup, custom move to wishlist by **knockout js**.

For knockout events, I created custom js and initialize it on `form.phtml`

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'remove-product'" id="cart-item-table">
    <form action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>"
              method="post"
              id="form-validate"
              data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
              class="form form-cart">

              ....
              ....
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
       "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "remove-product": {
                        "component": "Vendor_Module/js/removeproduct"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Now I have a third-party coupon code module which adds free gift product by applying the coupon code on cart page. For that, I just re-render item form layout on ajax response.

**Everything is working fine except knockout events on item form. All knockout events stop working after re-render item form.**

After some R&D, I found that we need to rebind knockout events after ajax response.

```
ko.applyBindings(removeproduct, $('#cart-item-table'));
```

It's showing error like parameter should ViewModel and element. I already defined it.

Any help would be appreciated...!

Comment: Same issue i face before few days. This link is helpful for me. Hope, you can get solution from this answer :)

Comment: I also have similar implementation in my project. But when I use applyBindings, it create extra rows in my lists. For eg: if I have 5 rows it shows 20 after applyBindings. Any clue what can be the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to re-bind the js component by knockout `applyBindings` function on the ajax response.

```
ko.applyBindings(new removeproduct(), $('#cart-item-table')[0]);
```

While `removeproduct` is viewModel(component) `Vendor_Module/js/removeproduct` and `cart-item-table` is the element which I need to re-bind knockout events.

### EDIT

If you have same component with each element, you can use the below code. For example, you have multiple product div in response and each product div has knockout binding

```
if ($.fn.applyBindings != undefined) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#recommend-products-cat').find('.product-item').trigger('contentUpdated');
        $('#recommend-products-cat').find('.product-item').applyBindings();
    }, 1000);
}
```

where `#recommend-products-cat` is main div. `.product-item` is child products divs.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: yes bhai!! hahaahaa

Comment: <script>
    require([
            'jquery',
            'ko',
            'Vendor_Modul/js/removeproduct'
        ],
        function ($, ko, rp) {
            ko.applyBindings(new rp(), $("#cart-item-table")[0]);
        });
</script>
is it right approach ?

Comment: I also have similar implementation in my project. But when I use applyBindings, it create extra rows in my lists. For eg: if I have 5 rows it shows 20 after  applyBindings. Any clue what can be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

It's better way to use `data-mage-init` into specific div instead of using `<script type="text/x-magento-init">`

**x-magento-init** will be call when module will be initialized. So, when module will be initialized at that time, **x-magento-init** script will be call. So, it will be not used for ajax response.

**data-mage-init** will be working same as like **x-magento-init** except it will call when that particular div will be load.

**Example :**

```
<div data-mage-init='{"Pulsestorm_JavascriptInitTutorial/example": {"another":"example"}}'>A single div</div>
```

Here, You can see on above code that when above div will be load at that time, js file will be execute. It's better way as per my view.

---

EDIT :

```
<div id="ko-example" data-bind="scope:'ko-example'">
    <!-- ko if: isVisible-->
    <div class="rh-module" data-mage-init='{"Rh_Module/js/kotemplate": {"another":"example"}}'>
        <div >A single div</div>
        <div id="rh-buttons" class="actions">
            <button type="submit" title="Select" class="action primary" id="rh-module-select-btn" data-bind="click:addCustomValue">
                <span>Select</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" title="Cancel" class="action" id="rh-module-cancel-btn">
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
           "components": {
                "ko-example": {
                    "component": "Vendor_Module/js/kotemplate",
                    "template" : "Vendor_Module/kotemplate"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

Here, `rh-module` only visible when isVisible true and that will be get only in ajax respose. So, when `<div class="rh-module">` visible kotemplate js will be call and you can bind data.

[More reference](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_init_scripts/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). There are only difference between `data-mage-init` and `text/x-magento-init` is that `data-mage-init` adds js component on specific HTML element while `text/x-magento-init` is no relation to a certain HTML element. Both types, initialized js component on DOM ready so it's not working on ajax response.

Comment: I just found the solution to my issue. We need to re-bind the js component by knockout  `applyBindings` function check my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks for new solution @Prince +1 from mine. Can you please elaborate more in your answer?

Comment: Thanks @Rohan I will update the answer soon :)